# PHP Double comparision

Tags: php, double, comparison, equality, php-internals

**PHP Version 7.1.7** / Laravel 5.4

```
dump($this_tour->payments_to_operator_sum());
```

> 1012.0

```
dump(gettype($this_tour->payments_to_operator_sum()));
```

> "double"

```
dump($this_tour->operator_price, gettype($this_tour->operator_price));
```

> "1012.00", "string"

```
dump((double)$this_tour->operator_price, gettype((double)$this_tour->opeartor_price);
```

> 1012.0, "double"

```
dump($this_tour->payments_to_operator_sum() == (double)$this_tour->operator_price);
```

> false

Why can it be false?

I am confused.

PS. I understand the difference between "==" and "===", I guess it has nothing to do with it. 
When I do:

```
dump((double)1012.0 == (double)"1012.00");
```

i get

> true

Answer (score 1):

when I did:

```
return $this_tour->payments_to_operator_sum()
```

(instead of 'dump'), I got:

> 1011.9999999999999

so this is the answer, I guess.